# Intellij suddenly throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

I'm at a complete loss here. I have a project on an external hard drive called LenseProject. Inside LenseProject, I have `.idea`, `lib`, `Natives` and `SRC` folders. I also have a number of text files for reading.

When I left work last night, this all worked fine. Coming in this morning, I'm met with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QuadTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
```

QuadTest being the main class.

Information that I think might be helpful:

- If I comment out the imports, I get the appropriate error messages.
  (Cannot find symbol, etc).
- I have 9 dependencies, located in lib\lwjgl-2.9.0\jar that are set up
  in Project Structure -> Libraries.
- The module has LenseProject as the content root, and SRC as the
  source folder.
- The language level is 7.0
- I have the dependencies set to export in Project Structure -> Modules
  -> Dependencies.
- In Compiler Output, I have it set to Use Module Compile Output Path,
  as Inherit Project Compile Output Path gave me "Cannot start
  compilation: The output path is not specified for module
  "LenseProject". Specify the output path in Configure Project.
- I have VM option `-Djava.library.path=Natives`.
- I can compile and run the program through command prompt no problem.
- I was missing my configure options when I started it up this morning. I had to set the SDK again, and libraries.

Comment: You need to download dependencies first then add it to the project classpath.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have the dependencies in the lib folder.

Comment: Have your tried to invalidate caches. often help with sudden errors.
File-> invalidate caches

Comment: Have you had found a solution for this issue? I'm facing the same but three years later :)

Comment: in 2020: a potential remedy, if using Gradle, is to edit your `build.gradle` and rebuild it

Answer (score 17):

Open your Idea File --> Project Structure  --> Modules ，and then choose problematic module，in the "Paths" tab change selected to "Use module compile output path ".

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a similar issue while writing unit tests.  Everything would work at the command line but failed in IntelliJ.  IntelliJ would successfully compile but not run the test.

Then I ran across a post on IntelliJ's blog: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-released/

> anet says:
>
> March 21, 2014 at 12:20 pm
>
> You may remove the existing junit dependency and allow IDEA to add JUnit library for your from scratch.
>
> New junit doesn’t bundle hamcrest anymore but still depends on it on runtime.
>
> Thanks,
> Anna
>
> - See more at: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-released/#sthash.2KNQuwZ5.dpuf

I removed JUnit from my project settings and let IntelliJ add it back.  Then things worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue. A new dependency was not being found when running tomcat. The problem was it wasn't being deployed to `/WEB-INF/lib`. After half a day banging my head on the desk I found this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDMRHGMDUtQ) that fixed it.

Essentially I needed to add the dependencies from module settings-> artifact->MyWar->Output Layout tab. Under available elements open your projects folder. If there are maven dependencies listed there, select them. Then right click->Put into /WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was I reused the "out" directory for program output.
I solved it by redirect the output to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest confirming your `Run Configuration` as follows:

Toolbar: `Run`->`Edit Configurations...`, confirm your Configuration is correct.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit old post but for me helped by going to Run-->Edit Configurations--> In Application Selected your main code file --> Configuration on the right panel. Checked "Use alternative JRE:" and selecting JDK folder called jre(.../Java/jdk.x.x.x_xx/jre). Apply and OK. I am really new with intelliJ but that solved my problem hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that all this renaming the project-structure, my Maven dependencies didn't mach.

After changing the maven dependencies in the pom file, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Project Structrure -> Project. 
Change the Project Language level from "SDK default" to Actual version that you are using.

This is weird, but solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mainClassName

mainClassName = "com.xxx.xxxApplicationKt"

Answer (score 0):

After bashing head into multiple times, the issue is resolved by downgrading the `Junit` version.

At the time of writing the latest `junit` version is `5.8.2`. However, after downgrading the version to `5.7.2` in the `pom.xml` the test successfully Run.

**Resolution 1 :** Update Java, if you're using `Java 8` check Java version with `java -version` if Java is added to Path(Windows)

From the Start Menu, and Java Folder, `Check for Updates`

**Resolution 2 :** Downgrade `junit` in `pom.xml`

**Resolution 3 :** Install the proper JDK latest version from Oracle [link-windows](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-windows) not from Google suggested link

Answer (score -3):

Try going to `Preferences -> Compiler` and select Eclipse, rather than using javac.

Comment: So why are you telling Intellij to select the Eclipse compilers?  The chances are, they won't be installed.  And is it even an option to select them?

Comment: @StephenC yes, it is an option.  Check it out.

Comment: OK ... so assuming that the Eclipse compilers are installed (a stretch!) ... >>why<< would changing the compilers fix what is essentially a runtime classpath problem?