# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I recently installed intellij IDEA 14.0 and to make sure everything was working I created a simple Hello World program. I do not understand why the output is not correct and why I am getting this error. If someone could please help that would be great.

This is the program:

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

Comment: Isn't that a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857849/intellij-suddenly-throwing-classnotfoundexception ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're getting this error is because you didn't save the class into a file called `Hello.java` (case-sensitive!)

Answer (score 3):

This is just problem of intellij IDE.

Solution Steps:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> -> **Preject Setting** -> **modules tab** -> **expand `<project_name>` and go to `<project_name>_main`**
2. refer Image: [image: SS1]
3. **In Sources tab** -> ** click on x symbol**

[image: SS2]

4. **click YES**
5. Right click on [image: SS4]  -> **sources**
6. Apply and OK

Finally build your project.

[image: SS7]

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens with IntelliJ.

I solved it deleting all modules and only leaving which have more hierarchy

The other modules(like main or test) are already part of product

[image]