# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I cloned my project from GitHub and now I am not able to run my project.

```
package edu.test.algorithm;

import edu.test.algorithm.Global;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Global global= new Global();
    global.runGlobal("-----url");
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.test.algorithm.Global.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

Any idea what's causing this error?

**EDIT**

I checked this question [Intellij suddenly throwing ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857849/intellij-suddenly-throwing-classnotfoundexception)before i posted here and it doesn't give me any solution.. Why marking my question as duplicate since that one isn't solving my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your Ide is wrong run/debug configuration

Main -> Edit Configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5KSL.png)

Check your IDE run configurations and Class

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Answer (score 1):

The exception message hints that you have used the wrong class name when launching the program.

You are (presumably) using `edu.test.algorithm.Global.Main` as the class name.  However you have actually declared `Main` in the package `edu.test.algorithm` which means that its full classname is actually `edu.test.algorithm.Main`.

If you didn't do this explicitly, it is possible<sup>1</sup> that you changed the `Main` classes package and neglected to change (or remake) the launcher config.

---

<sup>1 - I'm not familiar with Intellij ... but I know you can run into this kind of problem with Eclipse.</sup>