# fix ClassNotFoundException in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I have an project in GitHub and have some class.

I want to run a simple code.

```
public class team_32 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

But i face to this error.

I search in post of this error and do some guidance but this error is still.

this is some post I check :

[Error "ClassNotFoundException" in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300318/error-classnotfoundexception-in-intellij-idea)

[Intellij suddenly throwing ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857849/intellij-suddenly-throwing-classnotfoundexception)

please help me.

Exception:

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception please.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: i edit that_ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your configuration is somehow broken. I couldn't reproduce this on my machine, but I have an idea how you can move forwards.

The simplest thing to do to get this snippet of code working is to create a new project (File -> New -> Project). Select Java then next and check the Create project from template checkbox. Highlight Command Line App and hit next, enter a title and click finish.

You should then have a project with working defaults and should be able to paste your main method body into the provided one to get it running.